# Windows 10 keep freezing and running into blue screen error

Tags: windows-10, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card, optane

I created a custom CPU by buying parts individually for crypto mining. After flashing the device with windows 10, I am seeing the OS keep freezes and running into various blue screen errors. I am updating the bios, drivers from nvidia frequently. Each time its different blue screen error

System config

Intel I9 - 9900K
32 GB RAM (2x16 GB) - T-Force
Intel 512 SSD OPTANE Drive - nvme
Mother board Asus prime Z390-P

I am running cudo miner latest version, not sure if the issue is with my hardware or software. I installed Ubuntu to see if its OS issue, but I can see similar experience with Ubuntu 20 too. With Ubuntu it keep freezes and Throws error dialog that system ran into issue.

Windows Blue screen errors I am running into - (Honestly I feel windows is testing all the errors on me :( )

- watchdog timeout ( Most frequent one)
- page fault in nonpaged area

Anyone run into similar error? or any issue with my hardware configuration.

Comment: why did you tag this nvidia graphics card?

Comment: unplug the gpu and retry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled CPU and GPU mining at the same time, Once I disable CPU mining everything fallen into place.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem but with a different hardware, much older and dirty. So my windows was crashing every time that i run a game or something like that, heavy programs. What i did was clean the computer, but if you say its a new one I don't believe that's your problem, disconnected everything and change de SATA cables, already had spare cables. Maybe check your RAM and your hard drive.
I honestly don't really know what i did to stop the problem, but one of this did it. Hope this could help you! Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for responding, I disabled CPU mining and every thing fallen into place.